# Creating new variables in foreach loop?

Tags: powershell, loops, variables, foreach

I'm trying to loop through drive letters A-Z and output a new variable for each drive letter with the result to be taken by a monitoring program we use. Currently the code resets the variable, so I only get the result for a single drive letter (Z as it's the last in the loop). I’ve had a look into dynamic variables (I'm not sure if that's what I need) but I'm a bit lost…

Ideally I'd like it to output the following:

```
$DriveLetterResultA = $DriveLetterResult for $DriveLetter 'A'
$DriveLetterResultB = $DriveLetterResult for $DriveLetter 'B'
$DriveLetterResultC = $DriveLetterResult for $DriveLetter 'C'
$DriveLetterResultD = $DriveLetterResult for $DriveLetter 'D'
etc...
```

Here is non-working code:

```
$DriveLetters = [char[]](0..255) -clike '[A-Z]'
foreach ($DriveLetter in $DriveLetters) {
    $drive = New-Object system.io.driveinfo("$($DriveLetter)`:")
    $drive.DriveType
    $drive.DriveFormat
    if (($drive.DriveType -eq "Fixed") -and ($drive.DriveFormat -eq "NTFS" -or ($drive.DriveFormat -eq "FAT") -or ($drive.DriveFormat -eq "FAT32") -or ($drive.DriveFormat -eq "exFAT"))) {
        $DriveLetterResult = Repair-Volume -DriveLetter $DriveLetter -Scan -ErrorAction 0 -ErrorVariable RepairVolumeError
        if ($DriveLetterResult-eq "ScanRunning") {
            $DriveLetterResult = "ScanRunning (NoErrorsFound)"
        }
        if ($RepairVolumeError -ne "") {
            $DriveLetterResult= $RepairVolumeError | Out-String
        }
    } else {
        $DriveLetterResult = "NA (NoErrorsFound)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To what you want, you will need to utilize `Set-Variable` or `New-Variable`.

```
$DriveLetters = [char[]](65..90)
foreach ($DriveLetter in $DriveLetters) {
    $drive = New-Object system.io.driveinfo("$($DriveLetter)`:")
    $drive.DriveType
    $drive.DriveFormat
    if (($drive.DriveType -eq "Fixed") -and ($drive.DriveFormat -eq "NTFS" -or ($drive.DriveFormat -eq "FAT") -or ($drive.DriveFormat -eq "FAT32") -or ($drive.DriveFormat -eq "exFAT"))) {
        $DriveLetterResult = Repair-Volume -DriveLetter $DriveLetter -Scan -ErrorAction 0 -ErrorVariable RepairVolumeError
        if ($DriveLetterResult-eq "ScanRunning") {
            $DriveLetterResult = "ScanRunning (NoErrorsFound)"
        }
        if ($RepairVolumeError -ne "") {
            $DriveLetterResult= $RepairVolumeError | Out-String
        }
    } else {
        $DriveLetterResult = "NA (NoErrorsFound)"
    }
    Set-Variable -Name "DriveLetterResult$DriveLetter" -Value $DriveLetterResult -Force
}
```

The `-Force` switch will overwrite any read-only or constant variables of the same name already created.

Comment: Thank you so much this was exactly what I was after. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

How's this for a start.  This is the typical way a powershell script outputs a set of properties.

```
$DriveLetters = [char[]](0..255) -clike '[A-Z]'
foreach ($DriveLetter in $DriveLetters) {
    $drive = New-Object system.io.driveinfo("$($DriveLetter)`:")
    #$drive.DriveType
    #$drive.DriveFormat
    If (($drive.DriveType -eq "Fixed") -and
      ($drive.DriveFormat -eq "NTFS" -or ($drive.DriveFormat -eq "FAT") -or
      ($drive.DriveFormat -eq "FAT32") -or ($drive.DriveFormat -eq "exFAT"))) {
    $DriveLetterResult = Repair-Volume -DriveLetter $DriveLetter -Scan -ErrorAction 0 -ErrorVariable RepairVolumeError
        If ($DriveLetterResult-eq "ScanRunning") {
        $DriveLetterResult = "ScanRunning (NoErrorsFound)"
        }
        If ($RepairVolumeError -ne "") {
        $DriveLetterResult= $RepairVolumeError | Out-String
        }    }
    Else {
    $DriveLetterResult = "NA (NoErrorsFound)"
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
      DriveLetter = $DriveLetter
      DriveType = $drive.DriveType
      DriveFormat = $drive.DriveFormat
      DriveLetterResult = $DriveLetterResult
    }
}
```

Output:

```
DriveLetter       DriveType DriveFormat DriveLetterResult
-----------       --------- ----------- -----------------
A           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
B           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
C                     Fixed NTFS        Repair-Volume : Access denied...
D           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
E           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
F           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
G           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
H           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
I           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
J           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
K           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
L           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
M           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
N           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
O           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
P           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
Q           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
R           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
S           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
T           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
U           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
V           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
W           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
X           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
Y           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
Z           NoRootDirectory             NA (NoErrorsFound)
```

Comment: Thank for your help on this, that table is great but I need each Drive Letter result outputted as a separate variable in a string otherwise the program can't handle this type data.